# Como fazer subselect/subquery usando Criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

Alguém pode me ajudar a encontrar o problema dessa consulta :

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Solicitacao> query = builder.createQuery(Solicitacao.class);
    Root<Solicitacao> root = query.from(Solicitacao.class);
    Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
    Root<Envolvido> subRoot = subquery.from(Envolvido.class);
    subquery.select(subRoot.get(Envolvido_.solicitacao.getName()));
    subquery.where(builder.equal(subRoot.get(Envolvido_.isenIdp), isenIdp));
    subquery.where(builder.equal(subRoot.get(Envolvido_.isenIds), isenIds));
    query.where(builder.in(subquery));
    TypedQuery typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
    return solicitacaoResourceBean.initializeAll(typedQuery.getResultList());
```

Eu estou tentando fazer um subselect, eu consegui criar esse subselect com SQL, ele seria assim :

```
SELECT * FROM SOLICITACAO S WHERE S.SLCTC_ID IN (SELECT E.SLCTC_ID FROM ENVOLVIDO E WHERE E.ENV_ISEN_IDP = 61 AND E.ENV_ISEN_IDS = 1);
```

O Stack do erro :

````
    Hibernate: 
    select
        solicitaca0_.slctc_id as slctc_id1_59_,
        solicitaca0_.core_status as core_status2_59_,
        solicitaca0_.log_id as log_id10_59_,
        solicitaca0_.slctc_apelido as slctc_apelido3_59_,
        solicitaca0_.slctc_codigo as slctc_codigo4_59_,
        solicitaca0_.slctc_dt_criacao as slctc_dt_criacao5_59_,
        solicitaca0_.end_id as end_id11_59_,
        solicitaca0_.slctc_justificativa_finaliza as slctc_justificativ6_59_,
        solicitaca0_.ntrinc_id as ntrinc_id12_59_,
        solicitaca0_.slctc_prioridade as slctc_prioridade13_59_,
        solicitaca0_.slctc_regulador as slctc_regulador14_59_,
        solicitaca0_.slctnt_id as slctnt_id15_59_,
        solicitaca0_.slctc_status as slctc_status7_59_,
        solicitaca0_.slctc_tarm as slctc_tarm16_59_,
        solicitaca0_.slctc_tipo as slctc_tipo8_59_,
        solicitaca0_.slctc_tipo_regulacao as slctc_tipo_regulac9_59_,
        solicitaca0_.slctc_unidade_origem as slctc_unidade_ori17_59_ 
    from
        Solicitacao solicitaca0_ 
    where
        (
            select
                envolvido1_.slctc_id 
            from
                Envolvido envolvido1_,
                Solicitacao solicitaca2_ 
            where
                envolvido1_.slctc_id=solicitaca2_.slctc_id 
                and envolvido1_.env_isen_ids=?
        ) in (

        )
17-abr-2019 18:31:38,612 TRACE [BasicBinder] binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [null]
17-abr-2019 18:31:38,616 ERROR [ExceptionInterceptor] br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ApplicationLogicException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ApplicationLogicException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.ExecuteMethod.throwIfNotValidationException(ExecuteMethod.java:109)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.ExecuteMethod.execute(ExecuteMethod.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor130.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:299)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:277)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:255)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:269)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:258)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:92)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:78)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:60)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.interceptors.LogInterceptor.intercept(LogInterceptor.java:22)
    at br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.interceptors.LogInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:58)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.interceptors.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:34)
    at br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.interceptors.LoginInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:58)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.next(DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.java:49)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.interceptors.EntityManagerInterceptor.intercept(EntityManagerInterceptor.java:29)
    at br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.interceptors.EntityManagerInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor120.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at net.vidageek.mirror.provider.java.PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.invoke(PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.java:38)
    at net.vidageek.mirror.invoke.MethodHandlerByMethod.withArgs(MethodHandlerByMethod.java:54)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker.invokeMethod(StepInvoker.java:49)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker.tryToInvoke(StepInvoker.java:40)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.tryToInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor.executeAround(InterceptorExecutor.java:75)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.executeAround(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.execute(AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.java:85)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.interceptors.PerfilInterceptor.intercept(PerfilInterceptor.java:32)
    at br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.interceptors.PerfilInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:58)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.next(DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.java:49)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor.executeAround(InterceptorExecutor.java:77)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.executeAround(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.execute(AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.java:85)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor.intercept(FlashInterceptor.java:98)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:58)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.next(DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack.java:49)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.DefaultSimpleInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.next(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.exception.ExceptionInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionInterceptor.java:25)
    at br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.core.exception.ExceptionInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at net.vidageek.mirror.provider.java.PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.invoke(PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.java:38)
    at net.vidageek.mirror.invoke.MethodHandlerByMethod.withArgs(MethodHandlerByMethod.java:54)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker.invokeMethod(StepInvoker.java:49)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker.tryToInvoke(StepInvoker.java:40)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.StepInvoker$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.tryToInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor.executeAround(InterceptorExecutor.java:75)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InterceptorExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.executeAround(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.execute(AspectStyleInterceptorHandler.java:85)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.java:75)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:58)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:83)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.start(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:93)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.start(Unknown Source)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.RequestHandlerObserver.handle(RequestHandlerObserver.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:299)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:277)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:255)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:269)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:258)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:92)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
    at br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.solicitacao.SolicitacaoDAO.loadByEnvolvidos(SolicitacaoDAO.java:177)
    at br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.solicitacao.SolicitacaoBean.listarHistoricoPorEnvolvido(SolicitacaoBean.java:361)
    at br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.solicitacao.SolicitacaoController.listarPorEnvolvidos(SolicitacaoController.java:76)
    at br.com.consulfarmasaude.samu.solicitacao.SolicitacaoController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.listarPorEnvolvidos(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at net.vidageek.mirror.provider.java.PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.invoke(PureJavaMethodReflectionProvider.java:38)
    at net.vidageek.mirror.invoke.MethodHandlerByMethod.withArgs(MethodHandlerByMethod.java:54)
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.observer.ExecuteMethod.execute(ExecuteMethod.java:87)
    ... 115 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    ... 127 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: expressão não encontrada

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:774)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4845)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1501)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor77.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper.doExecute(JdbcWrapper.java:412)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$StatementInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:137)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:294)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 143 more```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver mudando um pouco a estratégia e usando outra Classe, a solução ficou assim :

```
    DetachedCriteria subSelect = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Envolvido.class, "env");
        subSelect.add(Restrictions.eq("env.isenIdp", isenIdp));
        subSelect.add(Restrictions.eq("env.isenIds", isenIds));
        subSelect.setProjection(Property.forName("env.solicitacao.id"));

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Solicitacao.class, "slctc");
        criteria.add(Property.forName("slctc.id").in(subSelect));
        return criteria.list();
```